# how to use StreamReader in C# to read only entries over a specific length to a list?

Tags: c#, random, streamreader

when using StreamReader in C# to load a txt file into a list, i assume that using a simple "If" the string's length is over a particular length, it will add it to the list. can anyone provide C# code for this? this IS homework, but it's NOT a C# class. the instructor would gladly provide this if i asked this specifically. thx.

the txt file is a dictionary of ~280,000 words, one per line. very simple move to turn into a list, but i'm wondering about getting words at least 2 characters long.

Comment: Do you mean with "List" a list of lines from the txt-File?
Or do you have multiple txt-files and you need a List of all files which are longer than X chars?

Comment: `File.ReadLines(..).Where(l=>l.Length > 2).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

Just use LINQ to give you a subset.

```
 List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
                          .Where(l => l.Length > specifiedWordLength)
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Use `ReadLines` to avoid reading all the file at once in memory

Comment: `ReadAllLines` reads _all_ lines into memory first, use `ReadLines` and you're also using a `StreamReader`(implicitly) as OP wants.